# Segmentation fault error in Hash table using vectors of pair data type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement a hash table using vectors of pair data type.I am thinking I have implemented the principle working of hash table without any compile errors but when I try to run it is throwing segmentation fault error.

## include

```
 #include <stdexcept>

 #include <string>

 #include <vector>

 using namespace std;

 template < class T >
  class HTable {
    private:
        vector < pair < string, T >> data;
    vector < bool > positions_in_use;
    size_t d_size;

    public:
        HTable(size_t size): d_size(size) {
            data.resize(d_size);
            positions_in_use.resize(d_size);
        };

    //hashing function to convert strings into indexes
    int hash(string key) {
        int hash = 0;
        int index;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
            hash = hash + (int) key[i];
        }
        index = hash % d_size;
        return index;
    };

    //Function to insert pairs into hash table using hash function    

    bool insert(const string & key,
        const T & value) {
        int index;
        pair < string, T > emptypair;
        index = hash(key);
        int pos = index;
        if (data.at(index) != emptypair) {
            typename vector < pair < string, T >> ::iterator it;
            data.insert(it + index, pair < string, T > (key, value));
            positions_in_use[index] = true;
            cout << "linear";
            return true;
        } else {
            bool foundplace = false;
            while (!foundplace) {
                pos++;
                if (data.at(index) == emptypair) {
                    typename vector < pair < string, T >> ::iterator it;
                    data.insert(it + pos, pair < string, T > (key,value));
                    positions_in_use[pos] = true;
                    foundplace = true;
                    return foundplace;
                } else if (pos == index) throw runtime_error("Hash Table is full!");            
                if (pos == d_size - 1)
                    pos = 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Function to get the value of key that is stored into hash table
    T & get(const string & key) {
        int index = hash(key);
        int pos = index;
        if (data.at(index).first == key) {
            return data.at(index).second;
        } else {
            bool foundkey = false;
            while (!foundkey) {
                pos++;
                if (data.at(pos).first == key) {
                    foundkey = true;
                    return data.at(pos).second;
                } else if (pos == index) throw runtime_error("Not contained in Hash Table!");
                if (pos == d_size - 1)
                    pos = 0;

            }
        }
    }

    //erase vector pair at certain index in hash table
    void erase(const string & key) {
        pair < string, T > emptypair;
        int pos = hash(key);
        int index = pos;
        if (data.at(index).first == key) {
            data.at(index) = emptypair;
            positions_in_use[index] = 0;
        } else {
            index++;
            if (index = d_size)
                index = 0;
            else if (index = pos) throw runtime_error("Not contained in Hash Table!");
        }
    }

    //clear entire hash table    
    void clear() {
        data.clear();
        positions_in_use.clear();
    }

    //display all the hash table contents     
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream & os,
        const HTable & h) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < h.data.size(); i++) {
            os << h.data[i].first << "," << h.data[i].second << endl;
        }
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {
  try {
    HTable < int > hs(10);
    int score = 43;
    string name = "peter";
    hs.insert(name, score);
    cout << hs;
  } catch (const exception & e) {
    std::cout << e.what();
  }
}
```

timeout: the monitored command dumped core
sh: line 1: 141719 Segmentation fault      timeout 10s

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: thing is I am using a online compiler.I cannot run a software at my machine to debug

Comment: You really should get a compiler on your machine so you can debug it.  If you are using windows MSVS community is a free full fledged C++ compiler and debugger.  If you have linux g++ or clang and GDB are both free and open source.

Comment: sure ,@NathanOliver I will check it over :)

Comment: If you absolutely can't then you can at least include `cout` statements and if checks in the code to test your assumptions to make sure they are valid.

Comment: `data.insert` changes the size of `data` vector, and shifts all the elements after the insertion point one position to the right. That'll throw off all your subsequent computations - previously inserted `key` is no longer at `data[hash[key]]`

Comment: What is `positions_in_use` for? You assign values to its elements, but never check those values.

Comment: position_in_use execution is incomplete so u can ignore as @IgorTandetnik  and  How should I insert at particular index ,I have tried using [] operator but it fails to insert data pair into vector

Answer (score 0):

`data.insert(it + index, ...)` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `it`

Comment: How can I insert data pair into vector using hash index ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to `insert`? Your design appears to rely on `data` having exactly `d_size` elements - calling `insert` would break that invariant. That said, if you are sure you want to, you could call it this way: `data.insert(data.begin() + pos, ...)`